# iOS run async method on background task?

Tags: ios, asynchronous, background-task

Stack Overflow. Here is what I´m dealing with.

I´m developing an iOS 8 app that starts monitoring significant location changes when app is terminated using `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()`. Until here everything works fine. The app relaunches when it get a location change with the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. I configure a `CLLocationManager` object and get the `CLLocation` like it says in Apple reference:

> If you start this service and your app is subsequently terminated, the
>   system automatically relaunches the app into the background if a new
>   event arrives. In such a case, the options dictionary passed to the
>   application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions: and
>   application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: methods of your app
>   delegate contains the key UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey to
>   indicate that your app was launched because of a location event. Upon
>   relaunch, you must still configure a location manager object and call
>   this method to continue receiving location events. When you restart
>   location services, the current event is delivered to your delegate
>   immediately. In addition, the location property of your location
>   manager object is populated with the most recent location object even
>   before you start location services.

Like I said, this works pretty well. My problem is when I try to fetch data from a web service (like Twitter API with `TwitterKit`) with a asynchronous method; I just not get onto the completion handler. I was researching a lot about this subject and I read that apparently the method I use is running in its own thread.

Here is how I listen to the location change launch and create the background task:

```
var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
var bgTaskId: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier!

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    // API keys configuration

    if let options = launchOptions {
        if options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey] != nil {

            self.bgTaskId = UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler({ () -> Void in
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().endBackgroundTask(self.bgTaskId)
                self.bgTaskId = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
            })

            // Location manager configuration

            // Async func
            theAsyncRequest(){ (response) -> Void in
                // 
                // NEVER GETS HERE
                //
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().endBackgroundTask(self.bgTaskId)
                self.bgTaskId = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
            }
        }

        return true
    }

    // Some code when app launches the normal way

    return true
}
```

I tried the same with a synchronous method like in *Parse Framework* eg. `let objects = someQuery.findObjects()` and it worked. But it doesn´t with an asynchronous method.

What do I´m missing in here? Is it possible what I´m trying to accomplish? I know this would be an easy task if I´d use a synchronous method.

Thanks in advance.